# C++ - Create variable names by concatenating strings possible?

Tags: c++

This may sound weird but I'm wondering if I can create variable names by passing in a string to a function that would then concatenate this string to other strings to create variables.

For example...

```
  checkForElement("foo");

  checkForElement(string name){

      int ___Count = 0;
  }
```

Where ___ would be replaced by foo.  I've never seen such a thing and think it's likely a no but just wanted to confirm.  I'm fine leaving it the way it is but I just was wondering if I could cut down 200 lines of code to 1/4 of that if I can avoid the duplication.

The reason I want to do this is that I'm parsing text for four different elements - I have this working already but I have a lot of repeated code of basically loops where the only difference is are the variable names I use in each.

I'm not that experienced with C++ so it could be that there are better ways of handling the parsing but for now I am iterating character by character.

Comment: Why do the variable names matter? If they are internal to the function, they don't affect anything. If they're from outside, they can be given as arguments.

Comment: Mainly because I'm storing everything into their own arrays

Comment: If you show a part of the actual code it might help, since the example you gave doesn't explain why an internal variable should have a different name

Comment: Sounds like [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) might help you here.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - I can't post code.  I was hoping the example was clear enough

Comment: @Galik - I'll give it a look!

Comment: It does not make it clear since changing the variable name inside a function has no side effects and as such has no meaning. If it was visible outside it might have some effect. It's the same as one's spouse calling them Honeybu's when they're together at home and nobody else hears. Sure it's cute between them, but everyone else is none the wiser :)

Comment: Hah nice analogy :)  Got it...thanks!

Comment: Many libraries support such run-time properties, for instance the [property system](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) in the Qt library. And there are many-many situations where this is useful, such as writing your own scripting interface